# Convert string array into JSON object?

Tags: java, json, gson

I got json[] from UI. I have to convert it into Json object how can I convert it with **`gson`**. An object which is received is like that:

```
 [{"name":"name","value":"value"},{"name":"first","value":"100"},{"name":"hor","value":"95"},{"name":"conf","value":"95"}],[{"name":"vaRType","value":"INCRE"},{"name":"per","value":"100"},{"name":"hor","value":"95"},{"name":"conf","value":"95"}]
```

I used `JsonObject obj = new JsoParser().parse(jsonStrnig).getAsJsonObject();`
but it throws an exception.

Comment: Maybe you mean `{{"a":a,"b":b,"c":c}, {"a":a,"b":b,"c":c}}`?

Comment: have you read any tutorial to convert json to java objetcs using gson? Its very simple. Just google it and you should fine one nice tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON should be the following as currently it's invalid...

```
[
    [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "first",
            "value": "100"
        },
        {
            "name": "hor",
            "value": "95"
        },
        {
            "name": "conf",
            "value": "95"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "name": "vaRType",
            "value": "INCRE"
        },
        {
            "name": "per",
            "value": "100"
        },
        {
            "name": "hor",
            "value": "95"
        },
        {
            "name": "conf",
            "value": "95"
        }
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 3):

Because it is not valid json object.